# Calcualte time different in Hrs, days, weeks and months between two epoch time string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am looking Javascript function two calculate time dereference between 2 epoch string.

> ```
> let time1 = new Date().getTime();
> let time2 = '1601213948000';
> ```

Also is there any moment function for same to get desired results.

Comment: [`.diff()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Answer (score 0):

The time difference between two epoch times is simply `time2 - time1`. If you need to convert an epoch string to a number, use `parseInt()`. Since the epoch time is measured in milliseconds, to calculate the difference in different units such as hours, days, weeks, and months, just use conversion ratios to convert the millisecond value to the desired unit (1ms = 0.001s, 1hr = 3600s, etc). If you want to format your epoch time into a human-readable string, you can use moment's `format()` method.

```js
let time1 = new Date().getTime();
let time2 = '1601213948000';
let difference = parseInt(time2) - time1;
moment(difference).format('MM/DD/YY');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [.diff()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) function

```
let timeA = moment();
let timeB = moment() - 1000 * 60 * 15;
timeA.diff(timeB, 'minutes'); // output is 15
```